# Cannot fetch data from api, Future always returns null - flutter

Tags: android, ios, api, flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch data from an API in a flutter. Just to test I was using the API URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 which has the following JSON object:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

I followed an example online almost exactly just tweaked to match the workflow I want but the `snapshot.hasData` below returns false.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final String accountNum;
  Home(this.accountNum);
  final String apiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchData() async {
    //accountNum below is passed from a previous screen, in this case I pass '1'
    //I printed it to make sure that '1' is passed and it is correct
    var result = await http.get(apiUrl+accountNum);
    //I printed the below and it also gave me the json from the api
    //print(json.decode(result.body));
    return json.decode(result.body);
  }

  String _MeterNum(dynamic account){
    return account['title'];
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Account Data'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
          future: fetchData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              print(_MeterNum(snapshot.data[0]));
              return ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                    return
                      Card(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 30,
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index]['picture']['large'])),
                              //I realize this will just show the same thing 
                              //but I was just keeping the format of the example I was following
                              title: Text(_MeterNum(snapshot.data[index])),
                              subtitle: Text(_MeterNum(snapshot.data[index])),
                              trailing: Text(_MeterNum(snapshot.data[index])),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                  });
            }else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },


        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What is returned is the `CircularProgressIndicator()` to the emulator screen indicating that `snapshot.hasData` is false. I don't get any error in the console or anything so I'm not sure how to proceed.

---EDIT---
Made changes to the code above using suggestions from the commenters:

> Changed return type from Future<List> to Future<Map<String, dynamic>> and changed 'return json.decode(result.body)['results'];' to 'return json.decode(result.body)'

And now I get the following error:

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
> FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(dirty, state:
> _FutureBuilderState<Map<String, dynamic>>#a10d4):
>
> The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null
>
> Tried calling:[] ("title")

Comment: your response is an json object and you are dealing with List<dynamic> thats the problem

Comment: To add to the comment above (change return type from Future<List<dynamic>> to Future<Map<String, dynamic>>): api resoponse does not have 'results' property, so you should change 'return json.decode(result.body)['results'];' to 'return json.decode(result.body)';

Comment: Well now I get an error. I have editted and added in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API response is a JSON object

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

and contains only `userId`,`id`, `title` and `completed` memebers

instead of referring to an index please consider getting from the object.

replace

```
snapshot.data[index]
```

with

```
 snapshot.data
```

also

```
snapshot.data['picture']['large']
```

you don't have `picture` data in the JSON object, Try to comment that code or add a picture to it

Comment: OMG THANK YOU. I HAVE BEEN TRYING TO SOLVE THIS FOR A LITERAL WEEK!

Comment: would you do me the priviledge in checking my latest question. Haven't been making any headway and couldn't find any other way to reach you,

Comment: Sorry I managed to figure it out  appreciate your reply tho, I was starting to get desperate

Answer (score 1):

Before checking for **hasData** do this:

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // your code
}
```

**EDIT**

Your request

```
var result = await http.get(apiUrl+accountNum);
```

returns JSON object not JSON List. But your ***fetchData*** method's return type was List before you updated it to Future<Map<String, dynamic>>.
Write your method like this

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchData() async {
    var result = await http.get(apiUrl+accountNum);
    return json.decode(result.body);
}
```

NO NEED FOR json.decode(result.body)['results'], because you are only fetching an object not a list.

Comment: I did if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) { print("connected"); } and got the "connected" but I also tried the two comments suggestion above and now I have an error! So that's something.

Comment: Hey, right I had also changed that but I produce the NoSuchMethodError in my EDIT above. Not finidng how to resolve this error, I have surmised that the snapshot grabs a null but the api is a simple example api that is functioning and the function is connecting so not sure.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
title: Text(_MeterNum(snapshot.data[index])),
subtitle: Text(_MeterNum(snapshot.data[index])),
trailing: Text(_MeterNum(snapshot.data[index])),
```

to

```
title: Text(_MeterNum(snapshot.data)),
subtitle: Text(_MeterNum(snapshot.data)),
trailing: Text(_MeterNum(snapshot.data)),
```

> there was no key as **['picture']['large']** so comment out the that key in **ListTile**